# how to indicate that a parameter is conditionally required when another parameter is used in Swagger Open API 3.0

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have created a RESTful API, and I am now defining the Open API 3.0 JSON representation for the usage of this API.

I am requiring usage of a parameter conditionally, when another parameter is present. So I can't really use either `required: true` or `required: false` because it needs to be conditional. Should I just define it as `required: false`, and then in the `summary` and / or `description` say that it is required when the other parameter is being used? Or is there a way of defining dependency between parameters? I haven't found anything [in the specs](https://swagger.io/specification/) that mention a case like this.

Comment: Parameter Dependencies
OpenAPI 3.0 does not support parameter dependencies and mutually exclusive parameters. There is an open feature request at https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/256. What you can do is document the restrictions in the parameter description and define the logic in the 400 Bad Request response. For example, consider the /report endpoint that accepts either a relative date range (rdate) or an exact range (start_date+end_date): - For more info - https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/

Comment: ok thanks, you could post it as an answer, the issue you referenced is exactly what I was looking for. I see I'm not the only one requesting this and I see a [mention was in fact made in the documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#dependencies)

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the docs:

**Parameter Dependencies**

OpenAPI 3.0 does not support parameter dependencies and mutually exclusive parameters. There is an open feature request at [github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/256](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/256). What you can do is document the restrictions in the parameter description and define the logic in the 400 Bad Request response.

- For more info - [swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters)

Comment: Unfortunately, Open API is far behind and it missing lots of useful things, like Generics types, Pick and Omit and much more

Answer (score 8):

See https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Swagger-Open-Source-Tools/Defining-conditional-attributes-in-OpenAPI/td-p/222410 where you can use anyOf around the required list of field

```
anyOf:
       - required: [longitude, latitude]
       - required: [postalCode, countryCode]
       - required: [city, state, countryCode]
```